# "comments.php" not available after edit in WP administration

Tags: php, comments, comment-form

In the theme "Point", the page "comments.php" is not translated properly.
I wanted to translate the labels manually (to french) in the WP administration editor but **when I update the file, the comments doesn't appear anymore on my website**.

Yet, I only changed the labels. Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Is this issue linked to the theme or to my WP installation?

**Here is the code before:**

```
    <?php

// Do not delete these lines
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
    <p class="nocomments"><?php _e('This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments','mythemeshop'); ?>.</p>
<?php return; } ?>
<!-- You can start editing here. -->
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <div id="comments">
        <div class="total-comments"><?php comments_number(__('No Comments','mythemeshop'), __('One Comment','mythemeshop'),  __('% Comments','mythemeshop') );?></div>
        <ol class="commentlist">
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
            </div>
            <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=mts_comment'); ?>
            <div class="navigation bottomnav">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
            </div>
        </ol>
    </div>
<?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>
    <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
        <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->
    <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
        <!-- If comments are closed. -->
        <p class="nocomments"></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
    <div class="bordersperator2"></div>
    <div id="commentsAdd">
        <div id="respond" class="box m-t-6">
            <?php global $aria_req; $comments_args = array(
                'title_reply'=>'<h4><span>'.__('Add a Comment','mythemeshop').'</span></h4></h4>',
                'comment_notes_after' => '',
                'label_submit' => 'Add Comment',
                'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">'.__('Comment:','mythemeshop').'<span class="required">*</span></label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="5" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
                'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields',
                    array(
                    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' 
                        . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'mythemeshop' ) . ':<span class="required">*</span></label>' 
                        . ( $req ? '' : '' ) . '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

                    'email' => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email Address', 'mythemeshop' ) . ':<span class="required">*</span></label>' 
                        . ( $req ? '' : '' ) . '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

                    'url' => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'mythemeshop' ) . ':</label>' . 
            '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>' 
            ))
            ); 
            comment_form($comments_args); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
```

**And here after the changes:**

```
<?php

// Do not delete these lines
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
    <p class="nocomments"><?php _e('This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments','mythemeshop'); ?>.</p>
<?php return; } ?>
<!-- You can start editing here. -->
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <div id="comments">
        <div class="total-comments"><?php comments_number(__('Pas de Commentaires','mythemeshop'), __('1 Commentaire','mythemeshop'),  __('% Commentaires','mythemeshop') );?></div>
        <ol class="commentlist">
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
            </div>
            <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=mts_comment'); ?>
            <div class="navigation bottomnav">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
            </div>
        </ol>
    </div>
<?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>
    <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
        <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->
    <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
        <!-- If comments are closed. -->
        <p class="nocomments"></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
    <div class="bordersperator2"></div>
    <div id="commentsAdd">
        <div id="respond" class="box m-t-6">
            <?php global $aria_req; $comments_args = array(
                'title_reply'=>'<h4><span>'.__('Ajouter un  Commentaire','mythemeshop').'</span></h4></h4>',
                'comment_notes_after' => '',
                'label_submit' => 'Ajouter un Commentaire',
                'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">'.__('Commentaire:','mythemeshop').'<span class="required">*</span></label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="5" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
                'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields',
                    array(
                    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' 
                        . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Nom', 'mythemeshop' ) . ':<span class="required">*</span></label>' 
                        . ( $req ? '' : '' ) . '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

                    'email' => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Adresse email', 'mythemeshop' ) . ':</label>' 
                        . ( $req ? '' : '' ) . '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

                    'url' => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Site internet', 'mythemeshop' ) . ':</label>' . 
            '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>' 
            ))
            ); 
            comment_form($comments_args); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
```

Comment: Revert back to the original file and then make only one edit at a time. Hopefully this will lead you to the precise line that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translated code seems to work fine. I tried putting it in `comments.php` of said theme, and the comments are appearing (at least when displaying single post). Try disabling plugins and check if you have accidentally deleted the call to `comments_template()`.

That being said this is really not the way you should be translating WordPress theme. There are a lot of tutorials on the subject, if you do a lot of translation you should probably check them out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It's working fine now. I know it's not a sustainable way but this is quite an exception so I did it in the "dirty way". The day I need to do more translations, I will follow your advice and do it in a more correct way.